# Django user is not authenticated when template is extended

Tags: python, html, django, templates, authentication

How to keep data_dictionary always in the template ? (Maybe not the right question) . **User should always be authenticated**
Explained:
This is the **base template** that is extended by all other templates. Its not possible to send data to base.html from all other templates so that if statement will work. The front end part can be understood by reading the base.html. All other templates of the app will be shown in the context and in the **right side bar** it ll be possible to see if the user in logging in or not an make some actions. BUT I cant get there. The only url that works is /loggedin. Do you have ideas how to make this plan work? Its something very simple but I cant get there with django.And i ve been told that there is no reason to use SESSIONS for user auth. Need Help. Plz be simple cause as you can see i am noob with Django and python. **Thank you**.

base.html :

```
<body>
<div id="page">

<div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/notes/all">Notes</a></li>

    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="rightsidebar">
    {% block rightsidebar %}

        {% if request.user.is_authenticated  %}
            Loggedin
        {% else %}
            Not Loggedin
        {% endif %}


    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}This is the content area{% endblock %}


</div>

</body>
```

Views.py:
....

```
def loggedin(request):
    my_data_dictionary = {}
    return render_to_response('base.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

...

Comment: The point is that *all* views should include that `context_instance` line.

Comment: How is this not possible to do? I think wrong logic. It should be other way.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. My comment is correct: *all* views, if you want to have the user status in the template, should include the `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`, or alternatively use the `render(request, template, context)` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to go depth in your own [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Also in view.py

```
def loggedin(request):
my_data_dictionary = {}
return render_to_response('base.html',
                      my_data_dictionary,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

add to this "my_data_dictionary" to var:{{value}} and {{user.username}} more info [authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates)

Comment: No its works fine in base.html. But then base.html is extended by an other templete->url->view does not work cause i dont return the data from other views. I want seen you login and send the my_data_dictionary its needed to do the same for all other views.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is in your settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    ....
```

And you can use {% if user.is_authenticated %} and {{user.username}} in your template.

Comment: Read  the comments for user fast plz above.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  If you want data_dictionary in all templates then maybe you need  write your own context processor?  When templates are extended it has no effect on the context that is available to them.

Comment: Do you anything to suggest me so that the rightside bar will work? . Don;t tell me there i no to way to do what i want in django? If in php it will be peace of cake.But i need to use python - django for that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to do it.I used session to permanently store my_data_dictionary and but it any views args.So now i can get it in any views i want and render it back to any views-> templates that extends  base.html and not particularity in the same template.
[SOLVED]

views.py.def_loggedin

```
def loggedin(request):
    my_data_dictionary = {}
    request.session['my_data_dictionary '] = my_data_dictionary <----------------------
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html',
                           my_data_dictionary,
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

any other view.

```
def notes(request):

    language = 'en-us'


    if 'lang' in request.COOKIES:
        language = request.COOKIES['lang']


    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['notes'] = Note.objects.all()
    args['language'] = language
    args['my_data_dictionary'] =  request.session['my_data_dictionary '] <-------



    return render_to_response('notes.html',
                                      args,
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request)) <---------
```

Comment: Its not working for all views but its a start ? Now do you understand what i need ???